# How to refer to a Camel SQL component named parameter where the parameter name is in mixed case and contains spaces?

Tags: postgresql, apache-camel

I am loading a CSV file into a Postgresql database using the Camel SQL component.
The original CSV file header names (Columns) are mixed case with spaces e.g. "Cost Price"

The SQL component refers to an SQL insert statement in a properties file,
e.g.
`insert into upload_data(year,month,cost)values(:#year,:#month,:#Cost Price)`

I get this error:
 Caused by: [org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException - PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":" at position...

-the position refers to the : before #Cost Price

If I change the parameter name to cost_price and modify the CSV file the file is uploaded correctly without error.

I have tried surrounding the parameter with " ' \" and {} in the insert statement

Is it possible to use mixed case with spaces in named parameters using escapes or something or do I need to intervene and modify the CSV header?

Comment: Another good example why you shouldn't use quoted identifiers in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL component does not support this, in fact its a real bad design to use spaces in header names. So after you read the CSV file, you can change the header name before calling the SQL component.

Comment: Ok understood. I cannot control the original file creation so I will have to modify it when its uploaded. Thanks.